# Secure static files with flask

Tags: python, security, static, flask, password-protection

I am building a flask application, and I want it to serve some static files only if the user is authenticated. It's a very low-traffic application (for internal use only). How would I go about this? One thing I was thinking of is using serve_static(), and putting that behind an authentication check but that uses the static directory which flask already serves content from.

Comment: Do you want to authentic only for *certain* static files or do you want authentication for *all* static files (and / or the whole application)?

Comment: All static files. I already have authentication on the app, so if I can check against the active session for the app that'd be perfect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply subclass `flask.Flask` and override the [`send_static_file`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.send_static_file) method:

```
class SecuredStaticFlask(Flask):
    def send_static_file(self, filename):
        # Get user from session
        if user.is_authenticated():
            return super(SecuredStaticFlask, self).send_static_file(filename)
        else:
            abort(403) 
            # Or 401 (or 404), whatever is most appropriate for your situation
```

See also [the definition of `send_static_file`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/94f436013792249a9bb7206c2868d4c6c21fd887/flask/helpers.py#L815) and following

Comment: There seems to no longer be a line 857 in that file.

Comment: @JesseAldridge - I've fixed the link to point at a fixed commit.  Thanks for the heads up!