# Override send_static_file() in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118485) to my problem, but I don't know how to it use correctly.

My code:

app = Flask(**name**)

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static", static_path="")

class SecuredStaticFlask(app):
    def send_static_file(self, filename):
        # Get user from session
        if current_user.is_authenticated():
            return super(SecuredStaticFlask, self).send_static_file(filename)

        else:
            abort(403)
```

When I visit `http://localhost:5000/some_existing_file` in the browser, Flask give me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/honza/Stažené/pycharm-community-3.0/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1498, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/home/honza/Stažené/pycharm-community-3.0/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1139, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "/home/honza/workspace/web_development/login/toneid_web_api_jk.py", line 37, in <module>
    class SecuredStaticFlask(app):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 507, in __init__
    self.add_url_rule(self.static_url_path + '/<path:filename>',
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Instance of flask.Flask is `app`, right? So, I think subclass of Flask is `subclass_name(parent_class)`.

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it should be in lines of :

```
class SecuredStaticFlask(Flask):
    def send_static_file(self, filename):
        # Get user from session
        if current_user.is_authenticated():
            return super(SecuredStaticFlask, self).send_static_file(filename)

        else:
            abort(403)
```

and

```
app = SecuredStaticFlask(__name__, static_folder="static", static_path="")
```