# Flask login_required to access sub-directory within static folder

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

`app.view_functions['static'] = login_required(app.send_static_file)` is working if I want to prevent access to the static folder without being logged in.

However this prevents the style.css being accessed. I want to prevent people accessing a subfolder of my static files Static > Images. I have tried to do this as follows:

`app.view_functions['static/Images'] = login_required(app.send_static_file)`

This isn't working, i.e. I can still access static/Images/... without being logged in.

If protecting a subdirectory isn't possible, can I change the location of my style.css to be outside of my static folder?

I am trying to protect sensitive Images being available to anyone with the path to the image. I can prevent `send_from_directory` being used without log in, but I also do not want someone with the `www.___./path_to_image` to be able to access it.

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Secure static files with flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118355/secure-static-files-with-flask)

Comment: I have tried to use this previously, but it isn’t working unfortunately. As far as I am aware it also doesn’t differentiate between static main and sub directories, which is the premise of my question.

Comment: I think the solution is not to hijack the static directory which is meant to be public files, but to put your sensitive files in another folder entirely.

Comment: Thanks @DanSafee, does send_static_file work with another folder? (I’m new to flask, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to add the files to a folder different from /static (which is supposed to be public), as explained in this answer:

[Restrict static file access to logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611671/restrict-static-file-access-to-logged-in-users)